# Can't package my application using electron-packager

Tags: npm, package, electron, node-modules

I am trying to build a test app using Electron in my Windows 7 x86. I have Node.js, npm, electron and electron-packager installed. The project's directory structure looks like this:

```
app
   package.json
   main.js
   index.htlm
```

I have the following in my package.json file:

```
{
    "name" : "TestApp",
    "main" : "main.js",
    "version" : "0.01",
    "scripts" : {
        "start" : "electron .",
        "package" : "electron-packager / TestApp --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --verson=0.30.2 --overwrite "
    }
}
```

And here is the image of what's happening,

[image]
after reading the script, it freezes (or I don't know what happens) and nothing happens. I waited for 15-20 minutes but there is no progress after reaching this step. Can someone please help!

Comment: In the command which I use, after electron-packager I have a . and not a /. Change that and see if it works. Also, you have a typo. It should be --version whereas you have --verson. You are missing the i.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your `npm package` command from within the `app` directory, the command in your package.json file should be configured as:

```
{
    "name" : "TestApp",
    "main" : "main.js",
    "version" : "0.01",
    "scripts" : {
        "start" : "electron .",
        "package" : "electron-packager . TestApp --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --verson=0.30.2 --overwrite "
    }
}
```

Note that the `electron-packager .` in the above line indicates the current location is the directory of the application to be packaged.